# Concatenate fields and eliminate all spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to **concatenate 10 different fields** in the same table. After the field concatenated, I need to **eliminate the space between** all characters. 30,000
records.

```
CUSTOMER #  FIELD 1          FIELD 3   FIELD 4   FIELD 5   FIELD 6   FIELD XX
            ,TO BE OR NOT,   /THAT IS/ /THE Q/   OR NOT     THE_       QUESTION
```

So, it would like like:

```
,TOBEORNOT,/THAT IS//THEQ/ORNOTTHE_QUESTION
```

Comment: Er - is there supposed to be a space between "THAT IS"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `concat` and `replace`:

```
select
  replace(concat(field1, field2,....), ' ', '')
from customer
```

To count the characters use `len`:

```
select
  len(replace(concat(field1, field2,....), ' ', '')) counter
from customer
```

Comment: What if there are spaces _inside_ the field?

Comment: All spaces will be replaced.

Comment: OP does not want that.

Comment: Look at the sample data

Comment: Actually the OP stated "eliminate the space between all characters" and you can see in the example that it has spaces removed within fields, except for "THAT IS" which I think is a typo.

Comment: yes, all spaces to be eliminated. We are trying to get a count of how many characters without the spaces. Is there a way to do a "Character Count" of the characters of each row after I we get rid of the spaces? Thanks a lot

Comment: @HelloCognos See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you folks, It is working now